# Setting the target language

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-to-text

How can i set the target language from english to lets suppose french?
i am using google translate api.

```
 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",sentenceToSpeeh];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already tried to change from

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=%@",sentenceToSpeeh];
```

to

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=%@",sentenceToSpeeh];
```

? :) so you can say

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=%@&q=%@",myLanguage, sentenceToSpeeh];
```

a gave it a try in the browser and it worked fine :)

Comment: accepted but for a up vote i need to have at least 15 reputations :(

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings - In info you will see Localizations button under that you will see + button. Tap on that and you will get all available language options to add.

[image]